# Utilizando sessões em arquivo de configuração em CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

No meu projeto, preciso fazer algumas tarefas, que dependem de informações que estão no banco de dados. Armazeno essas informações em sessões, para utilizar em todo o meu projeto.

Uma dessas tarefas é conectar com diversos bancos de dados, e as informações desses bancos vêm de um banco principal, sendo assim, armazeno estas informações em sessões, só que preciso dessas informações do banco no arquivo *database.php*.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como faço para recuperar estas informações que estão em sessões, neste arquivo de configuração?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o seu caso, acredito que você tenha que criar uma configuração extra durante a execução do programa. De [acordo com a documentação](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) você pode alterar a configuração do DB da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$this->load->database($config);
```

Ou então utilizar duas configurações ao mesmo tempo:

```
$dbBase = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$dbUser = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);

// Dispara query para o banco principal
$dbBase->query();

// Dispara query para o banco do usuario
$dbUser->query();
```

Basta alterar no *array* `$config` os parâmetros que você tem na sessão (fora do arquivo `database.php`).

```
$config['hostname'] = $this->session->userdata('host');
$config['username'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
$config['password'] = $this->session->userdata('password');
$config['database'] = $this->session->userdata('database');
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Comment: já tentei dessa forma, mas não obtive sucesso, pois ele sempre buscava as configurações do arquivo 'database.php'

Comment: Isso você alteraria não no arquivo de configuração, mas na execução do seu controller por exemplo.

Comment: Ainda sem sucesso, quando faço dessa forma ele me retorna um erro "Call to a member function select() on a non-object in"

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 poderia inserir alguns trechos de código da sua aplicação ? Testei aqui em um projeto novo e funcionou.

Comment: Amigo, houve um erro meu de digitação, agora está funcionando perfeitamente.